# Python 3 - multiple AsyncIO connections

Tags: python-3.x, chat, python-asyncio

I am trying to learn how to use AsyncIO in Python 3.7 and I am still a little confused by its principles.

My goal is to write a simple chat program, however I need to use a ring network topology -- one node only knows about its two neighbours. When the message is sent, it is passed by the nodes until it reaches the sender again. This means that each node is basically a client and a server at the same time.

I also need to be able to detect dead nodes, so that my ring does not break.

I thought it might be a good solution for each node to have a separate connection for every neighbour -- `successor` and `predecessor`.

```
class Node:
    ...
    def run():
        ...
        s = loop.create_connection(lambda: Client(...), addr1, port1)
        p = loop.create_server(lambda: Server(...), addr2, port2)
        successor = loop.run_until_complete(s)
        predecessor = loop.run_until_complete(p)
        loop.run_forever()
        ...
    ...
```

`Server` and `Client` are classes that implement `asyncio.Protocol`.

The reason I wanted to do it this way is, that if there is a message being sent through the circle, it is always sent from the `predecessor` to the `successor`. In `connection_lost` method of the `predecessor` I can detect that it is disconnected and send its `predecessor` a message (through the whole ring) to connect to me.

I would like to be able to send a message that I received from my `predecessor` further on to my `successor`. I would also like to be able to send a message with my address to my `successor` in case my `predecessor` dies (this message would be sent from `predecessor`'s `Server.connection_lost()` and would be passed all the way to my dead `predecessor`'s `predecessor`).

**My question is:** Can I pass the received data from `predecessor` to `successor`? If not, what would be a better implementation of this program that uses AsyncIO and the ring topology?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For anyone new to AsyncIO having the same problem, I found the solution myself.

First of all, it is better to use the high-level aspects of AsyncIO -- `streams`. Calling `loop.create_connction` and `loop.create_server` is considered low-level (which I understood wrong at first).

The high-level alternative to `create_connection` is `asyncio.open_connection`, which will supply you with a tuple consisting of `asyncio.StreamReader` and `asyncio.StreamWriter` which you can use to read from and write to the open connection. You can also detect the loss of the connection when the data read from the `StreamReader` equals to `b''` or when you catch an exception (`ConnectionError`) while trying to write to the `StreamWriter`.

The high-level alternative to `create_server` is `asyncio.start_server`, which needs to be supplied a callback function that will be called every time a connection to the server is made (open connection, received data...). The callback has `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` as arguments. The loss of the connection can be also detected by receiving `b''` or `ConnectionError` on writing to the `writer`.

Multiple connections can be handled by coroutines. There can be a coroutine for the server part (which accepts the connection from one of the neighbors in the ring topology) and a coroutine for the client part (which opens a connection to the other neighbor in the ring). The `Node` class can look like this:

```
import asyncio

class Node:
    ...
    async def run(self):
        ...
        self.next_reader, self.next_writer = await asyncio.open_connection(self.next_IP, self.next_port)
        server_coro = asyncio.create_task(self.server_init())
        client_coro = asyncio.create_task(self.client_method())
        await client_coro
        await server_coro
        ...

    async def server_init(self):
        server = await asyncio.start_server(self.server_callback, self.IP, self.port)
        async with server:
            await server.serve_forever()

    async def client_method(self):
        ...
        try:
            data = await self.next_reader.read()
        except ConnectionError:
            ...
    ...
```

Note that I am using `asyncio.create_task` for the coroutines and (not here in the code listing) `asyncio.run(node.run())`, which are considered high-level alternatives of `asyncio.ensure_future()` and `loop.run_forever()`. Both of these were added in Python 3.7 and `asyncio.run()` is said to be provisional, so by the time you read this, is might already have been replaced by something else.

I'm not an AsyncIO expert, so there might be a better, cleaner way to do this (if you know it, please share it).